# Programming language and automation tool to automate mainframe as/400

Tags: automated-testing, tools, languages

Which programming language would you prefer to automate the screens of a mainframe system like IBM AS/400?

Comment: What protocol do you use to connect?  TN5250?

Answer (score 1):

What works for sure is screen automation with Sikuli/Python.

Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Comment: can you give detail on how you would accomplish it?  Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: I used Sikuli for desktop automation (Windows software). But since Sikuli is Screenshot based, it can automate literally anything. A good place to start is http://www.sikuli.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Java is a good choice, but actually just take your pick: RPG, assembly language, C, C++, Pascal, Java, EGL, Perl, Smalltalk, COBOL, SQL, BASIC, PHP, PL/I, Python and REXX. There is also a set of CASE tools.

You may want to restrict yourself to the ILE (Integrated Language Environment)  compatible languages though. Also important is the OS400 
Control Language (CL).

An entrance level reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_i#Programming

Comment: And which tools will you use those languages in to automate AS400 screens?

Comment: Ah, screen automation. On the mainframe I'd just use Proterm. On OS400: http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/developer/general/Automated-Testing-of-iSeries-Applications/ or some variation, because I have no experience using TestBench.